# Hive query takes longer than expected

Tags: hadoop, hive

We are working on a collection of hive queries for our business users and noticed that this specific query takes a lot of time:

```
SELECT t.country, t.site, t.year, a.name, COUNT(t.*)
from 
(SELECT DISTINCT country, site, year, month FROM signals) t, 
(SELECT DISTINCT site, country, name from master_data) a 
WHERE t.site = a.site and t.country = a.country 
GROUP BY t.country, t.site, t.year, a.name;
```

Each subselect by itself takes about 25 seconds.
The query without grabbing the name takes 2 minutes, but as soon as 
the join comes in time is exploding.

Do you have an idea why the execution time increases that rapidly?

P.S. `t` returns 90 entries and `a` returns 263

Comment: check explain plan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you use `EXPLAIN` or `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` (more details see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Explain) to see how the query is being actually executed. Studying the execution plan can reveal the reason.

By default Hive uses Map Reduce as execution engine. You might try the execution engine to tez which is much more efficient when it comes to complex queries. Add the following line before the `SELECT` statement.

```
set hive.execution.engine=tez;
```

Looking at your query. Without `name` the right sub-select in the join (named `a`) will return much less records when `name` is not included. Most likely in a magnitude of 10.

Try to use the JOIN clause with specifying the join predicates in the join. The execution plan is different and much more optimal:

```
SELECT t.country, t.site, t.year, a.name, COUNT(t.*)
from 
(SELECT DISTINCT country, site, year, month FROM signals) t, 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT country, site, name from master_data) a 
      ON t.site = a.site and t.country = a.country 
GROUP BY t.country, t.site, t.year, a.name;
```

Try also the version without sub-selects:

```
SELECT t.country, t.site, t.year, a.name, COUNT(t.*)
FROM signals t, 
INNER JOIN master_data a 
      ON t.site = a.site and t.country = a.country 
GROUP BY t.country, t.site, t.year, a.name;
```

Comment: The link posted for understanding of hive joins is no loner Valid!